# Print a table in Bash

Tags: bash, printf, echo

I have a problem to print all values from array to print a nice table using printf function or echo. I have tried simple while but its not in the order i would like to.

```
    for i in ${!R[@]}
    do
      printf "%-20s" ${R[i]}
      printf "\n"
    done
```

[image: what i have]
[image: what i want]

What i want

```
 mteEventComment mteEventActions mteEventEnabled mteEventEntryStatus
                           "80 "            true              active
                           "80 "            true              active
                           "80 "            true              active
                           "80 "            true              active
                           "80 "            true              active
                           "80 "            true              active
```

What i have

```
 mteEventComment mteEventActions mteEventEnabled mteEventEntryStatus
       "80          "        "80          "        "80
         "        "80          "        "80          "
       "80          "       true       true       true
      true       true       true     active     active
    active     active     active     active
script2.sh: line 64: "80: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""80")



 content of **R array**: First 6 are empty
         "80 " "80 " "80 " "80 " "80 " "80 " true true true true true true active active active active active active
```

I have the header

```
printf "$header" "mteEventComment" "mteEventActions" "mteEventEnabled" "mteEventEntryStatus"


mteEventComment mteEventActions mteEventEnabled mteEventEntryStatus
```

under this i need my array in exact order

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I cannot see the images. Please copy the input and outputs as text to the post, not as images.

Comment: try the images now...

Comment: Please copy __the text__ from the images into your post. Please don't post images and please don't post links. I still don't understand why some people find it easier to make a screenshot and post it on imgur and then copy the link and then post the link to imgur, rather then just copying the text itself...

Comment: cut-n-paste the text of current and desired output into code blocks in your question; it would also help if you showed us the contents of the array, eg, what is in `R[0]`, `R[1]`, `R[2]`, etc.

Comment: Cool. Now that is that over with, what are the content of `R` array? The current code you posted, doesn't produce the output you indicated as `What i have`.

Comment: Can you just post the output of `declare -p R`? It would be more reusable and more readable then `content of **R array**: First 6 are empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the data in R contain values (and potentially keys) with special characters (quotes, spaces), you want to quote them:

```
for i in "${!R[@]}" 
    do
      printf "%-20s\n" "${R[i]}"
    done
```

Comment: Why not just `printf "%-20s\n" "${R[@]}"` then?

Comment: That's a good idea. I will leave it to the Kajim to decide if we want to use this, as this may be make it harder to understand and support the code - not everyone is aware of this behavior (repeat last format as needed ...)